# Не получается передать null в Expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity

Есть такой рабочий код:

```
     string tempTitle = filter.Title ?? string.Empty;
     string tempAddress = filter.Address ?? string.Empty;

     var query = this.db.ShopRepository.Read(m =>
                       (m.address.Contains(tempAddress))
                    || (m.shop_id.Contains(tempTitle))
                 )
                 .OrderBy(shop => shop.shop_id)
                 .ToList();




    public virtual IQueryable<T> Read(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expressionWhere)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(expressionWhere);
    }
```

Как `Linq` переделать в вид :

```
var query = this.db.ShopRepository.Read(m =>
                           (filter.Address == null || m.address.Contains(filter.Address))
                        || (filter.Title == null || m.shop_id.Contains(filter.Title))
                     )
                     .OrderBy(shop => shop.shop_id)
                     .ToList();
```

Ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`42P08: не удалось определить тип данных параметра $1`

Comment: Это скриншот исключения? (>_<) Вы же здесь не первый день, вроде. Будьте добры опубликовать текстом тип, сообщение об ошибке и трассировку стека.

Comment: Еще укажите какую библиотеку используете для подключения к БД. Если это [EF6.Npgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/), то там есть баги с передачей строк в `IS NULL` ([пример](https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/issues/87)). В данном случае их легко обойти с помощью первого варианта, вроде он не так уж и плох. Почему он не устраивает?

Comment: @defaultlocale юзаю именно ее EF6.Npgsql. Выриант не устраивает т к далее фильтры состоят не из 2х значений....а так же добавляются сложные объекты